# Can I hook an event right after "like" button is clicked, but before post on News Feeds?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I know I can hook on edge.create event to know when the "like" button is clicked. But on my test, I found this event is actually fired after the link is posted on FB News Feeds. And what I am going to do is to take an AJAX action, and compose a new URL before the link is actually posted on News Feeds. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Where your like button? On facebook group page, or on your website ?